# Extracting text string from file, assigning them to variables then writing them to another file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Basically, its a game server (minecraft) and I have a situation where I am attempting to automate new world generation. Basically, I have a file that gets generated happily which has this snippet in it.

file1.txt

```
keepSpawnInMemory: 'true'
spawnLocation:
  ==: MVSpawnLocation
  yaw: 0.0
  pitch: 0.0
  z: 256.5
  y: 62.0
  x: -223.5
autoLoad: 'true'
bedRespawn: 'true'
```

This works fine, but I need to extract the z: 256.5, y:62.0 and x: -223.5 respectively and then write a file called file2.txt with the following lines.

```
 world: mine
 x: -223.5
 y: 62.0
 z: 256.5
 yaw: 0.0
 pitch: 0.0
 name: mine
```

I assume I'll be using something like awk to extract the initial numbers, assigning them to variables then writing the file? I have never used awk before, and I am insanely confused. Appreciate any help in this guys. Im using Ubuntu linux, bash scripts. Can I extract text like that and make them into variables using awk and bash?

EDIT:

I did forget to mention that the file 1 has multiple instances of x,y and z. It can be accessed here: http://pastebin.com/TqaLcWzV

Is there a way to start at a certain line? For example, z, y and x will always be on lines 183, 184 and 185 respectively.

Comment: Do you need only x, y, z lines from file1?

Comment: Yeah, yaw and pitch will always be 0, so they dont really need to be allocated to a variable. Apologies also, the example file 2 should have the same numbers as the first file for the x,y and z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE1=/path/to/file1
FILE2=/path/to/file2

#extracting lines 183 to 185
FILE1=$(awk 'FNR>=183&&FNR<=185' $FILE1)

#extracting variables    
Z=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep z: | awk '{print $2}')
Y=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep y: | awk '{print $2}')
X=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep x: | awk '{print $2}')
#YAW=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep yaw: | awk '{print $2}')
#PITCH=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep pitch: | awk '{print $2}')

cat <<EOF > $FILE2
 world: mine
 x: $X
 y: $Y
 z: $Z
 yaw: 0.0
 pitch: 0.0
 name: mine
EOF
```

If you want it to also extract the YAW and PITCH:

- Change the awk line to extract from line 181:

  ```
  FILE1=$(awk 'FNR>=181&&FNR<=185' $FILE1)
  ```
- Uncomment the `YAW` and `PITCH` lines
- Change the yaw: and pitch: at the very bottom to be:

  ```
  yaw: $YAW
  pitch: $PITCH
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to *assign* the values to variables? Since the `variable: value` pairs appear identically in both the input and output, you could just extract them textually, e.g.

```
$ awk '/mine:/,/allowFlight/ {if ($1 ~ /^[xyz]:/) print;}' file1.txt
      z: 256.5
      y: 62.0
      x: -223.5
```

You could put that directly in a here-document using command substitution I think:

```
cat > file2.txt << EOF 
 world: mine
$(awk '/mine:/,/allowFlight/ {if ($1 ~ /^[xyz]:/) print " "$1,$2;}' file1.txt)
 yaw: 0.0
 pitch: 0.0
 name: mine
EOF
```

(I prettified the output a little by using `print " "$1,$2` instead of a simple `print`).